# Drupal OpenLayers Module JS error

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, openlayers-3

I've created a form (using [FormEntity](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform)) that contains a Map to record user input location (see [example](http://mapali.re/mission-drone-formulaire)). Everything works (almost) fine except that I've got a weird JS error when I want to draw a polygon or a point on the map. The error is : TypeError: c.N(...) is undefined.

I've tried to use the ol-debug.js library to have more details about the error, but when I do that I don't have the possibility to draw anymore.

Another strange thing is, this map works perfectly fine during the configuration step of the CCK field. I can draw on the map and I don't have any error. This one happens only on the main page.

Do you have any idea what is wrong ?

Thanks for your help

Arnaud